# Get the symbol name of the function's nth argument

Tags: variable-definitions, symbols

I tried this:

```
Plo[fun__] := SymbolName @ Part[List @@@ Unevaluated @@ {Hold[fun]}, {1}, 2]
SetAttributes[Plo, HoldAll]
```

On `Plo[aaa,bbb]` it writes

```
SymbolName::sym: Argument Unevaluated[bbb] at position 1 is expected to be a symbol.
```

When I write manually the returned value

```
SymbolName[Unevaluated[bbb]]
```

it works..

Comment: Try with `Plo[fun__] := With[{tmp = Part[List @@@ Unevaluated @@ {Hold[fun]}, {1}, 2]}, SymbolName[tmp]]`.

Comment: Thanks, works. Is it because the HoldAll applied inside? But I also tried to have the symbolname outside the function .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following does what you want:

```
SetAttributes[Plo,HoldAll] 
Plo[fun__]:=SymbolName@@{Unevaluated@@Hold[fun][[{2}]]}
```

Besides some cleanup of your function, the key fix is the use of `Apply` to apply `SymbolName` to the `Unevaluated[…]` expression. To understand the difference, it is important to realize the following: When the evaluator is evaluating an expression of the form `head[arg1,arg2,…]`,`head` is evaluated first. After this, the arguments are considered one after the other: If evaluation is prevented by a `Hold*` attribute, nothing is done. Otherwise, if the argument is wrapped in `Unevaluated`, the wrapper is removed, and nothing more is done. Otherwise, the argument is evaluated normally. The key here is that only `Unevaluated` wrappers literally present when first starting this process have the intended effect. Once the evaluation of an argument has begun, it can't be "stopped" midway through. If an `Unevaluated` wrapper appears as part of the evaluation of the argument, it is simply ignored. This is exactly what happens in your code. The code above circumvents this by making sure the `Unevaluated` wrapper is literally present before the expression `SymbolName[…]` is constructed.

Comment: @DanielHuber Unless I'm missing something, that's not necessary? `Pattern` has attribute `HoldFirst`, so `fun` having a value doesn't cause any problems (at least in my testing)

Comment: Sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the "nth" argument is supposed to be, since `n` does not appear in the OP, just `2`.  So here's a way to get the name of a `Symbol` argument for a fixed `n`, as in the OP:

```
plo // ClearAll;
SetAttributes[plo, HoldAll];
With[{nMinusOne = 2 - 1},
 plo[Repeated[_, {nMinusOne, nMinusOne}], arg_, ___] := 
   SymbolName@Unevaluated@arg;
 ]

Block[{bb = 3}, plo[aa, bb, cc, dd]]

(*  "bb"  *)
```

Another way; this time with an adjustable `n` depending on a global variable `$myN` (one could make it an argument to `plo[n, fun]` but the need is unclear):

```
plo // ClearAll;
SetAttributes[plo, HoldAll];
$myN = 2;
plo[fun__] := With[{n = $myN},
   Function[, SymbolName@Unevaluated@Slot[n], HoldAll][fun]
   ];

Block[{bb = 3, cc = 7, $myN = 3}, plo[aa, bb, cc, dd]]

(*  "cc"  *)
```

After seeing the OP's application of this problem, I thought of this way to get the output of the OP's answer without having to use `Part`:

```
getArgs // ClearAll;
getArgs // Attributes = {HoldAll};
getArgs[fun__] := AssociationThread[
   List @@ SymbolName /@ Unevaluated /@ Hold[fun] -> {fun}];

Block[{bb = 3}, getArgs[aa, bb, cc, dd]]

(*  <|"aa" -> aa, "bb" -> 3, "cc" -> cc, "dd" -> dd|>  *)
```

`(ToString[#, InputForm] &)` might be a better transformation of the arguments to strings than `SymbolName` (for both `getArgs[]` and `plo[]`). It's rare that the arguments in my function calls are all symbols.
Also `getArgs[f_[fun___]] :=...` seems more likely to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer in the comments, I can create Association that associates arg names to args. Could be useful.  (`Keys@GetArgs[...][[n]]` is the nth arg)

```
CreateAssoication[z_] := Association[ #[[1]] -> #[[2]] & /@ z];
GetArgs[fun__] := 
  CreateAssoication@
   Table[With[{tmp = 
       Part[List @@@ Unevaluated @@ {Hold[fun]}, {1}, 
        k]}, {SymbolName[tmp], Evaluate[tmp]}], {k, 1, 
     Length[Hold@fun]}];
SetAttributes[GetArgs, HoldAll];
```

Comment: Did you forget `SetAttributes[getArgs, HoldAll];`?

Comment: yes, indeed , I forgot